How to find the earliest observation of each species for every sampling night pr. id
I need help to find out when every species (MANUAL.ID) has the earliest observation (TIME) for every sampling night (DATE.12) and Location (id). My problem is that R always believes the earliest observation of the night is the earliest observation after midnight.
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("2024-07-30", 
"2024-07-31", "2024-08-05", "2024-08-06", "2024-09-12", "2024-09-13", 
"2024-09-05", "2024-09-06", "2024-08-03", "2024-08-02", "2024-08-01", 
"19/08/2024", "20/08/2024", "21/07/2024", "03/08/2024", "02/08/2024", 
"20/07/2024", "2024-07-20", "2024-08-20", "2024-08-19", "2024-07-19", 
"2024-07-21", "2024-08-07", "2024-09-15", "2024-09-16", "2024-07-28"
), class = "factor"), MANUAL.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), levels = c("EPTSER", "Myotis sp.", "Noise", "NYCNOC", "PIPNAT", 
"PIPPIP", "PIPPYG", "", "NoID", "MYODAU", "OBS", "VESMUR", "PIPPYG  SOCIAL", 
"PIPPYG  SOCIAL + EPSTER", "PIPPIP SOCIAL", "PIPPYG + PIPPIP", 
"OBS - EPSTER?"), class = "factor"), TIME = structure(c(68L, 
27L, 6L, 67L, 10L), levels = c("00:00:20", "00:30:41", "01:03:50", 
"01:09:12", "01:09:21", "01:10:54", "01:11:02", "01:17:20", "01:24:47", 
"01:24:52", "01:25:50", "01:26:32", "01:26:37", "01:35:50", "01:38:50", 
"01:41:33", "01:41:38", "01:53:30", "01:56:02", "02:06:18", "02:06:50", 
"02:21:07", "02:21:12", "02:21:40", "02:27:44", "02:32:07", "02:32:12", 
"02:32:17", "02:34:35", "02:52:40", "03:05:10", "03:14:10", "03:32:38", 
"04:19:56", "05:36:30", "06:41:00", "06:50:20", "06:54:20", "07:17:10", 
"19:15:30", "19:47:30", "19:52:00", "21:04:20", "21:32:40", "22:47:20", 
"22:50:55", "22:51:46", "23:02:00", "23:02:10", "23:05:00", "23:06:50", 
"23:11:40", "23:17:00", "23:22:30", "23:24:40", "23:28:35", "23:39:00", 
"23:39:21", "23:41:06", "23:41:40", "23:44:20", "23:49:43", "23:49:48", 
"23:54:30", "23:55:33", "23:55:38", "23:55:56", "23:56:02", "23:56:07", 
"23:58:48", "21:35:30", "03:31:00", "02:08:50", "22:40:20", "22:47:10", 
"22:11:10", "00:35:30", "01:30:40", "23:26:40", "00:42:20", "23:20:10", 
"05:04:50", "23:27:00", "03:52:10", "03:36:04", "03:35:57", "03:35:49", 
"03:35:47", "03:35:26", "03:28:05", "03:28:00", "03:27:35", "03:26:44", 
"03:26:36", "03:26:30", "03:26:18", "03:25:53", "03:25:30", "03:25:22", 
"03:12:30", "03:12:25", "03:12:06", "03:11:44", "03:10:19", "03:10:10", 
"03:01:47", "03:01:41", "03:01:15", "03:01:09", "03:00:18", "03:00:03", 
"02:59:41", "02:40:33", "02:40:27", "02:40:15", "02:39:52", "02:39:17", 
"02:25:39", "02:25:01", "02:14:15", "02:14:04", "02:13:37", "02:13:10", 
"02:13:05", "02:12:38", "02:12:32", "02:10:37", "02:10:24", "02:09:55", 
"02:06:27", "02:05:08", "02:05:01", "02:04:55", "02:04:40", "02:02:29", 
"02:01:53", "02:01:42", "02:01:39", "02:01:34", "02:01:11", "02:00:28", 
"01:59:34", "01:59:20", "01:59:15", "01:59:01", "01:36:45", "01:36:36", 
"01:36:31", "01:36:07", "01:36:01", "01:35:54", "01:35:26", "01:35:19", 
"01:34:46", "01:34:37", "01:34:12", "01:34:04", "01:33:57", "01:33:15", 
"01:33:06", "01:32:55", "01:31:02", "01:30:37", "01:30:12", "01:30:05", 
"01:29:52", "01:27:07", "01:27:02", "01:26:35", "01:25:19", "01:25:13", 
"01:24:48", "01:23:46", "01:23:34", "01:23:07", "01:04:47", "01:04:42", 
"01:04:32", "01:04:23", "01:04:03", "01:03:25", "01:02:48", "01:02:19", 
"01:02:10", "01:01:58", "01:01:03", "01:00:57", "00:59:52", "00:59:39", 
"00:59:34", "00:59:21", "00:58:59", "00:58:46", "00:58:04", "00:57:53", 
"00:55:33", "00:55:23", "00:54:59", "00:53:45", "00:53:38", "00:41:35", 
"00:41:30", "00:40:42", "00:40:35", "00:40:29", "00:39:58", "00:39:53", 
"00:39:49", "00:39:22", "00:38:46", "00:38:38", "00:37:28", "00:37:24", 
"00:35:45", "00:35:36", "00:32:49", "00:32:43", "00:32:23", "00:31:58", 
"00:31:52", "00:31:45", "00:22:31", "00:22:25", "00:22:16", "00:21:25", 
"00:21:19", "00:20:50", "00:20:38", "00:20:27", "00:13:41", "00:13:00", 
"00:12:54", "00:12:23", "00:12:17", "00:12:10", "00:12:03", "00:11:45", 
"00:09:26", "00:08:53", "00:07:03", "00:06:57", "00:06:32", "00:06:24", 
"00:05:54", "00:05:45", "00:05:08", "00:04:38", "00:04:27", "23:43:12", 
"23:43:02", "23:42:20", "23:42:10", "23:41:56", "23:41:48", "23:41:10", 
"23:40:40", "23:40:01", "23:39:58", "23:39:52", "23:34:55", "23:34:50", 
"23:34:40", "23:34:14", "23:34:08", "23:28:31", "23:28:26", "23:27:58", 
"23:27:51", "23:22:14", "23:18:18", "23:18:13", "23:17:43", "23:07:51", 
"23:07:46", "23:07:33", "23:07:27", "23:07:14", "23:07:09", "23:06:52", 
"23:06:46", "22:50:36", "22:39:03", "22:38:47", "22:38:30", "22:38:19", 
"22:37:52", "22:37:29", "22:37:16", "22:36:59", "22:36:12", "22:35:59", 
"22:35:48", "22:35:37", "22:35:24", "22:35:14", "22:34:37", "22:34:26", 
"22:34:13", "22:30:28", "22:30:23", "22:30:18", "22:23:02", "22:22:56", 
"22:22:15", "22:22:08", "22:05:53", "21:34:29", "21:34:23", "21:34:21", 
"21:34:16", "21:22:04", "21:09:17", "03:41:50", "03:41:44", "03:41:38", 
"03:41:21", "03:41:16", "03:41:05", "03:41:00", "03:40:51", "03:40:45", 
"03:40:41", "03:40:34", "03:40:16", "03:39:50", "03:27:33", "03:27:28", 
"03:27:16", "03:23:42", "02:50:35", "02:40:25", "02:30:42", "02:30:37", 
"02:30:27", "02:30:14", "02:30:11", "02:19:23", "02:17:36", "02:07:24", 
"02:07:02", "02:06:57", "02:06:48", "02:06:42", "02:06:37", "02:06:14", 
"02:06:09", "02:05:57", "02:05:51", "02:05:46", "02:05:40", "02:01:20", 
"02:01:14", "01:58:49", "01:58:43", "01:58:33", "01:58:28", "01:58:23", 
"01:58:18", "01:58:06", "01:58:02", "01:57:57", "01:57:51", "01:41:14", 
"01:29:41", "01:29:34", "01:29:28", "01:29:22", "01:29:17", "01:29:11", 
"01:28:59", "01:28:52", "00:51:16", "00:51:10", "00:50:55", "00:50:49", 
"00:50:41", "00:50:36", "00:50:31", "00:50:25", "00:22:26", "00:21:16", 
"00:21:02", "00:20:56", "00:06:54", "00:06:11", "00:06:05", "00:05:52", 
"00:05:48", "00:05:34", "00:05:29", "23:32:30", "23:26:15", "23:20:55", 
"23:20:43", "23:02:12", "22:59:28", "03:50:49", "03:47:09", "03:26:24", 
"03:25:50", "03:25:19", "03:24:58", "03:24:50", "03:24:33", "03:24:26", 
"03:24:21", "03:23:05", "03:22:53", "03:22:06", "03:21:29", "03:21:21", 
"03:21:16", "03:21:02", "03:20:51", "02:52:20", "02:52:09", "02:52:03", 
"02:43:43", "02:43:38", "02:40:58", "02:19:17", "02:19:12", "02:19:03", 
"02:19:00", "02:18:55", "02:18:50", "02:18:41", "02:18:33", "02:18:26", 
"02:18:11", "02:17:56", "02:17:49", "02:17:46", "02:17:33", "02:17:28", 
"02:17:20", "02:17:14", "02:17:07", "02:17:01", "02:15:50", "02:02:40", 
"02:02:34", "01:53:16", "01:53:10", "01:47:57", "01:47:52", "01:45:44", 
"01:45:39", "01:45:34", "01:30:04", "01:26:14", "01:26:09", "01:24:05", 
"01:24:00", "01:23:54", "01:23:29", "01:23:01", "01:18:17", "01:18:12", 
"01:18:06", "01:17:43", "01:17:31", "01:17:02", "01:16:57", "01:09:27", 
"01:09:22", "01:02:29", "01:02:24", "01:02:18", "00:59:38", "00:57:10", 
"00:49:14", "00:29:36", "00:22:02", "23:50:50", "23:43:29", "23:43:25", 
"23:39:44", "23:34:01", "23:33:15", "23:27:48", "23:18:54", "23:18:48", 
"23:15:02", "22:51:52", "22:45:21", "21:37:29", "21:37:18", "21:37:06", 
"20:43:25", "21:03:02", "02:39:42", "00:34:57", "01:53:05", "00:21:23", 
"03:47:55", "00:21:48", "02:12:33", "03:30:57", "00:42:00", "23:50:17", 
"00:02:20", "00:44:48", "00:44:36", "00:44:03", "00:46:00", "00:21:03", 
"02:07:31", "02:15:11", "03:47:47", "23:46:33", "00:37:30", "00:37:36", 
"00:21:18", "00:46:54", "00:39:39", "00:55:45", "02:12:23", "02:57:18", 
"02:52:52", "02:57:23", "02:52:47", "03:07:59", "03:08:04", "03:18:45", 
"03:37:21", "03:54:54", "20:42:02", "20:43:38", "20:42:20", "23:13:11", 
"23:12:22", "23:22:04", "23:50:05", "23:56:59", "23:57:05", "23:59:57", 
"00:05:18", "00:06:33", "00:24:52", "00:27:16", "00:27:11", "00:43:42", 
"00:51:59", "00:54:58", "00:55:51", "01:13:12", "00:46:20", "01:16:09", 
"01:16:26", "01:16:31", "01:24:31", "01:24:25", "01:18:28", "01:31:28", 
"01:35:42", "01:25:18", "01:44:05", "01:54:34", "02:05:21", "02:35:29", 
"04:05:53", "04:38:32", "23:53:50", "23:53:40", "23:44:54", "23:45:12", 
"00:39:34", "00:17:11", "00:39:16", "23:14:50", "02:30:50", "21:57:14", 
"21:56:11", "01:48:28", "21:58:46", "02:06:12", "23:45:27", "22:54:28", 
"01:16:39", "03:18:50", "23:30:32", "00:15:38", "00:10:44", "01:23:18", 
"00:48:05", "02:56:23", "23:46:07", "02:29:43", "01:23:13", "01:16:34", 
"00:02:35", "01:00:47", "00:48:00", "00:16:41", "00:16:08", "02:29:14", 
"02:29:58", "00:30:40", "00:15:44", "02:29:19", "22:54:34", "00:08:12", 
"02:29:03", "00:16:13", "23:14:55", "22:05:19", "03:22:34", "22:25:11", 
"00:02:32", "00:10:38", "23:13:58", "23:43:37", "01:01:35", "03:54:31", 
"04:22:59", "00:02:45", "02:00:24", "23:51:18", "00:51:17", "22:36:58", 
"03:54:26", "00:02:08", "01:43:59", "03:15:10", "00:55:34", "22:08:15", 
"02:39:38", "21:30:49", "23:31:35", "00:12:06", "00:02:27", "03:54:36", 
"01:43:54", "04:38:58", "22:23:07", "00:55:20", "02:05:15", "03:22:16", 
"00:02:22", "00:42:45", "03:55:07", "03:54:59", "00:55:10", "23:31:30", 
"03:52:43", "23:31:48", "02:08:19", "03:18:32", "02:08:14", "03:08:10", 
"02:11:54", "02:12:28", "02:38:03", "23:31:43", "00:54:44", "03:15:35", 
"03:54:09", "01:43:49", "02:37:38", "03:02:58", "22:07:58", "00:54:49", 
"00:54:55", "00:55:29", "03:37:46", "02:37:43", "02:39:27", "22:22:26", 
"04:39:03", "04:47:24", "02:45:02", "01:54:39", "03:59:32", "02:46:20", 
"00:42:39", "01:51:55", "03:55:22", "01:16:53", "01:44:22", "04:22:06", 
"03:55:27", "00:01:44", "04:15:14", "00:18:51", "00:27:00", "02:36:29", 
"23:26:28", "04:15:09", "22:07:53", "23:46:35", "01:44:27", "03:30:52", 
"23:11:29", "00:51:08", "00:55:11", "01:13:46", "04:05:26", "02:57:28", 
"00:43:14", "01:52:00", "00:55:39", "02:00:12", "02:05:27", "00:55:15", 
"01:16:44", "00:20:18", "00:46:35", "00:51:23", "02:45:08", "04:06:13", 
"00:45:19", "02:04:33", "04:14:44", "04:14:28", "00:55:36", "02:44:35", 
"02:43:01", "03:59:05", "03:37:52", "03:54:21", "00:01:59", "00:45:00", 
"01:59:39", "00:45:37", "01:28:36", "01:56:12", "00:24:51", "02:46:45", 
"01:28:51", "23:54:49", "00:46:59", "01:59:54", "03:01:58", "00:46:49", 
"23:46:26", "23:12:17", "02:15:26", "23:54:54", "02:46:19", "02:13:27", 
"02:31:47", "01:16:06", "01:56:57", "23:55:30", "01:57:12", "02:48:59", 
"02:48:54", "04:00:40", "02:49:04", "01:42:43", "01:45:46", "03:41:14", 
"01:13:34", "23:02:43", "01:08:38", "23:50:11", "01:43:31", "22:06:16", 
"01:25:16", "21:55:46", "22:32:36", "00:03:00", "01:43:58", "03:21:51", 
"03:37:30", "03:41:24", "23:02:46", "03:20:20", "03:33:07", "21:56:40", 
"21:59:25", "21:58:37", "23:07:05", "23:05:14", "01:05:08", "23:55:11", 
"00:32:58", "01:08:22", "01:16:50", "01:30:55", "02:21:37", "02:31:10", 
"02:31:42", "02:47:37", "03:02:13", "03:03:39", "03:20:08", "03:41:09", 
"21:17:13", "22:02:37", "22:08:14", "03:40:11", "22:26:23", "22:51:06", 
"22:51:19", "22:50:53", "23:11:41", "23:22:20", "23:22:25", "23:55:15", 
"23:56:40", "23:57:10", "00:00:02", "00:00:11", "00:02:19", "00:02:37", 
"00:02:24", "00:00:21", "00:02:46", "00:02:54", "00:06:02", "00:12:28", 
"00:15:00", "00:15:07", "00:15:27", "00:15:21", "00:15:32", "00:18:29", 
"00:18:23", "00:20:37", "00:22:01", "00:22:41", "00:25:15", "00:25:01", 
"00:22:46", "00:25:38", "00:25:51", "00:26:27", "00:26:44", "00:42:24", 
"00:42:18", "00:43:03", "00:43:56", "00:44:53", "00:45:04", "00:46:47", 
"00:50:32", "00:50:38", "00:51:32", "00:55:27", "00:56:27", "01:12:35", 
"01:12:41", "01:15:52", "01:16:10", "01:21:23", "01:16:55", "01:21:41", 
"01:24:08", "01:24:46", "01:31:39", "01:31:50", "01:43:09", "01:43:22", 
"01:44:02", "01:59:53", "01:59:59", "01:59:48", "02:04:26", "02:04:10", 
"02:04:04", "02:07:29", "02:35:47", "02:35:52", "02:36:30", "02:43:08", 
"02:43:34", "02:43:47", "02:44:04", "02:44:18", "02:44:24", "03:16:41", 
"03:16:30", "03:17:22", "03:18:15", "03:19:22", "03:21:13", "03:21:24", 
"03:22:02", "03:21:40", "03:27:59", "03:27:27", "03:26:19", "03:28:46", 
"03:29:56", "03:30:35", "03:30:55", "03:32:37", "03:31:01", "03:34:56", 
"03:36:12", "03:37:25", "03:37:47", "03:39:54", "03:41:13", "03:46:47", 
"03:54:45", "03:54:39", "03:59:33", "04:06:14", "04:14:32", "04:15:05", 
"04:14:54", "01:52:31", "23:53:54", "03:18:13", "00:51:43", "23:14:54", 
"22:49:27", "22:48:59", "01:58:14", "01:55:56", "02:51:23", "22:37:09", 
"22:36:37", "02:26:19", "01:36:16", "03:38:30", "23:00:25", "02:17:21", 
"02:05:30", "23:15:00", "02:27:54", "22:51:33", "04:23:03", "01:29:12", 
"00:51:38", "22:19:08", "00:43:38", "04:05:51", "00:49:59", "00:44:59", 
"04:14:43", "00:21:44", "00:44:01", "00:12:14", "00:50:54", "00:45:18", 
"00:22:30", "00:51:05", "01:24:22", "00:51:49", "00:55:49", "00:42:51", 
"00:51:21", "00:46:41", "01:13:47", "02:04:32", "00:45:29", "00:46:18", 
"00:42:40", "00:46:36", "03:55:20", "00:46:12", "00:44:24", "23:30:56", 
"23:59:13", "00:56:09", "00:45:34", "00:45:55", "22:05:25", "00:50:16", 
"01:25:11", "00:21:50", "00:43:43", "02:48:39", "23:19:25", "01:12:56", 
"02:35:57", "00:46:23", "01:44:08", "00:50:48", "04:38:56", "00:10:36", 
"02:43:23", "00:55:12", "04:05:44", "00:44:13", "01:51:51", "00:26:16", 
"00:43:11", "00:43:49", "23:57:47", "01:13:42", "02:07:53", "00:43:17", 
"00:00:27", "00:55:07", "01:12:51", "00:46:01", "00:46:06", "00:18:35", 
"00:52:11", "01:13:07", "01:16:21", "04:03:45", "00:44:37", "04:38:33", 
"23:40:51", "00:32:08", "00:43:33", "00:55:38", "01:43:43", "02:44:13", 
"00:46:31", "01:24:17", "00:22:15", "00:46:52", "00:51:54", "00:55:21", 
"04:05:56", "00:44:31", "00:44:19", "01:54:35", "22:05:20", "01:54:13", 
"00:44:07", "01:24:41", "00:55:54", "03:59:21", "04:14:27", "23:22:02", 
"00:50:10", "01:51:38", "01:54:30", "00:15:41", "03:59:04", "22:25:09", 
"01:51:29", "02:07:59", "00:42:35", "00:45:13", "01:42:19", "01:21:18", 
"23:11:47", "02:08:09", "04:21:47", "03:55:09", "04:15:10", "04:02:07", 
"00:09:44", "00:56:22", "02:07:47", "00:50:43", "02:44:30", "00:05:17", 
"00:18:40", "00:56:33", "01:13:53", "01:53:45", "02:05:22", "01:43:48", 
"00:58:13", "01:06:36", "21:30:46", "04:02:13", "00:21:55", "00:50:21", 
"00:54:52", "02:43:39", "00:03:24", "00:49:40", "00:49:54", "02:05:07", 
"02:05:16", "00:20:19", "00:26:55", "01:44:17", "02:43:03", "23:11:34", 
"22:50:46", "00:26:03", "00:26:22", "01:24:33", "00:14:51", "00:27:06", 
"01:51:56", "02:35:31", "01:51:21", "01:42:25", "00:45:47", "00:20:49", 
"02:04:37", "00:51:27", "03:22:33", "03:59:10", "00:20:43", "00:25:24", 
"00:44:42", "22:32:30", "23:50:06", "23:57:15", "00:17:55", "00:50:05", 
"02:00:10", "00:32:11", "00:18:14", "01:51:44", "00:18:08", "00:26:38", 
"23:57:53", "00:50:27", "02:44:56", "03:38:36", "23:43:34", "00:45:40", 
"00:54:47", "01:24:02", "01:31:33", "01:51:35", "22:16:56", "22:17:11", 
"00:12:46", "00:45:24", "01:42:54", "04:15:00", "00:12:34", "01:42:20", 
"01:33:52", "01:08:44", "00:18:52", "01:24:28", "23:26:29", "23:46:39", 
"23:11:28", "23:46:34", "00:12:56", "03:55:25", "23:09:46", "00:52:17", 
"00:09:50", "04:14:37", "04:38:51", "00:06:28", "02:36:25", "03:55:15", 
"01:27:38", "03:29:07", "01:13:28", "01:42:16", "02:00:04", "04:06:10", 
"02:33:43", "02:33:20", "23:56:51", "23:57:41", "00:06:34", "04:22:07", 
"00:05:33", "02:04:45", "00:11:58", "00:21:08", "04:06:04", "00:12:41", 
"01:42:49", "02:44:40", "01:13:33", "04:14:48", "04:21:58", "22:32:52", 
"23:57:22", "01:13:21", "01:43:02", "02:35:42", "00:03:08", "00:05:43", 
"00:25:57", "00:50:59", "00:43:23", "00:54:42", "00:00:16", "00:22:10", 
"02:35:26", "03:59:16", "04:05:39", "02:36:08", "00:03:19", "01:29:56", 
"00:16:43", "01:33:47", "01:06:04", "01:27:45", "00:35:09", "23:54:52", 
"23:13:08", "00:04:30", "23:05:30", "01:16:42", "23:13:13", "02:53:42", 
"23:55:06", "00:11:48", "03:10:15", "02:53:47", "02:47:13", "01:36:22", 
"23:02:37", "03:20:46", "01:17:17", "00:11:54", "21:05:56", "03:37:41", 
"03:43:40", "03:29:46", "01:27:31", "02:47:18", "01:02:13", "22:25:41", 
"03:21:03", "03:37:04", "03:41:46", "03:45:07", "23:57:04", "03:30:02", 
"03:20:14", "22:28:51", "22:23:00", "02:59:40", "00:05:50", "01:33:00", 
"21:34:30", "00:20:30", "01:59:00", "03:00:40", "00:40:40", "01:59:30", 
"04:42:30", "23:28:30", "00:06:20", "00:21:30", "01:25:20", "01:34:40", 
"03:25:20", "01:59:40", "02:15:20", "04:40:21", "04:32:00", "05:35:00", 
"05:34:50", "04:41:10", "05:34:40", "23:34:10", "23:43:10", "00:05:20", 
"00:32:20", "00:39:20", "00:59:20", "01:30:10", "01:34:30", "02:04:30", 
"02:01:10", "02:01:50", "21:22:00", "21:21:50", "23:46:00", "00:17:40", 
"21:27:00", "01:01:00", "01:07:20", "23:07:30", "02:56:30", "02:10:30", 
"02:46:50", "01:59:50", "01:56:20", "02:07:40", "00:21:10", "01:29:00", 
"02:15:30", "00:45:50", "07:22:00", "01:42:30", "02:51:00", "23:19:09", 
"23:44:08", "00:52:13", "00:57:22", "01:14:41", "00:44:54", "20:40:20", 
"03:39:16", "22:42:11", "02:17:44", "01:46:55", "20:33:04", "22:43:01", 
"21:52:36", "01:46:16", "22:43:11", "21:42:02", "22:31:52", "03:33:22", 
"21:35:49", "01:45:14", "21:17:10", "21:20:19", "22:42:16", "03:21:08", 
"02:39:10", "21:25:19", "00:39:37", "20:40:04", "04:18:16", "23:27:30", 
"02:47:50", "00:11:19", "22:45:31", "03:19:07", "00:17:57", "02:02:05", 
"23:44:02", "01:19:36", "22:45:43", "03:42:35", "02:38:23", "23:44:13", 
"02:57:49", "04:20:33", "01:58:24", "23:31:10", "00:51:28", "01:14:35", 
"00:01:50", "06:50:36", "00:21:28", "23:27:45", "00:20:10", "21:19:30", 
"03:38:10", "00:22:00", "01:59:58", "07:12:02", "07:13:25", "01:19:23", 
"02:01:51", "02:46:09", "21:27:09", "23:30:10", "02:03:21", "22:06:46", 
"22:47:55", "02:00:44", "22:45:52", "02:04:12", "02:00:54", "02:02:36", 
"02:03:31", "02:02:18", "02:01:01", "02:03:26", "02:01:31", "02:01:25", 
"02:01:07", "02:01:57", "02:02:51", "03:34:30", "01:25:44", "02:01:48", 
"02:03:15", "02:00:50", "00:11:14", "00:33:16", "22:48:06", "00:10:48", 
"00:11:02", "01:31:57", "02:01:36", "02:01:43", "02:03:41", "00:10:33", 
"23:43:35", "00:21:53", "00:56:12", "00:37:56", "02:00:42", "02:02:24", 
"02:02:45", "02:03:00", "02:03:11", "00:09:58", "00:10:14", "02:26:16", 
"03:01:52", "01:19:28", "00:32:14", "05:45:10", "07:21:30", "20:52:40", 
"07:22:20", "07:18:30", "07:18:40", "07:22:10", "07:23:20", "07:28:20", 
"07:23:10", "07:18:50", "07:29:50", "07:29:40", "07:24:10", "21:01:00", 
"07:23:00", "03:32:40", "07:19:40", "07:21:40", "07:29:30", "06:33:40", 
"07:19:30", "07:24:20", "07:28:40", "07:27:40", "01:19:20", "07:23:30", 
"07:22:30", "05:47:40", "06:28:00", "07:20:20", "07:20:40", "07:19:20", 
"07:20:30", "07:21:00", "07:28:30", "07:16:00", "04:42:50", "23:07:40", 
"07:16:50", "07:16:10", "07:19:00", "07:19:50", "07:23:40", "07:28:50", 
"21:01:20", "06:50:10", "00:03:50", "05:21:40", "00:04:50", "07:18:20", 
"07:24:50", "02:51:20", "01:40:50", "23:02:20", "23:39:30", "02:32:40", 
"23:11:10", "07:24:00", "21:13:00", "00:01:30", "22:30:50", "23:42:40", 
"21:53:50", "21:41:00", "00:28:40", "03:40:00", "06:38:00", "06:20:10", 
"07:15:40", "07:21:20", "07:28:10", "21:39:00", "22:35:10", "22:52:40", 
"00:02:30", "23:51:40", "00:03:10", "00:04:00", "00:14:30", "05:28:00", 
"05:17:40", "05:28:20", "06:00:40", "22:00:20", "22:56:00", "23:24:50", 
"02:02:30", "02:03:20", "02:07:50", "02:11:10", "02:11:20", "04:16:40", 
"04:49:20", "05:45:30", "05:48:50", "06:39:00", "06:58:00", "06:59:20", 
"00:36:10", "00:36:20", "22:07:20", "22:08:50", "00:27:20", "01:09:10", 
"21:56:10", "23:32:00", "00:33:30", "01:03:10", "01:09:20", "01:10:30", 
"01:16:30", "01:18:00", "22:53:20", "23:11:30", "23:23:00", "23:36:00", 
"00:49:20", "01:02:20", "01:08:20", "01:09:40", "01:15:50", "01:19:10", 
"22:05:30", "22:55:30", "22:55:00", "22:54:50", "22:57:40", "23:09:40", 
"23:11:20", "23:13:20", "23:14:10", "23:14:30", "23:21:00", "23:26:50", 
"23:25:20", "23:27:10", "23:36:30", "00:23:40", "00:24:20", "00:24:50", 
"00:32:31", "00:32:50", "00:34:20", "00:48:10", "01:04:30", "01:04:20", 
"01:04:00", "01:07:40", "01:08:30", "01:10:40", "01:11:10", "21:54:40", 
"22:01:50", "22:05:00", "22:06:40", "22:08:00", "22:09:30", "22:11:50", 
"22:14:30", "22:56:40", "22:57:00", "23:04:10", "22:58:20", "23:06:00", 
"23:04:40", "23:09:10", "23:06:30", "23:08:20", "23:09:00", "23:10:20", 
"23:11:50", "23:13:00", "23:19:30", "23:25:30", "23:29:50", "23:27:20", 
"23:30:20", "23:31:00", "23:33:00", "23:35:40", "23:34:20", "23:37:40", 
"00:23:30", "00:26:30", "00:29:00", "00:29:50", "00:28:10", "00:32:00", 
"00:31:40", "00:33:20", "01:01:40", "01:02:40", "01:04:10", "01:03:20", 
"01:04:50", "01:06:10", "01:06:20", "01:05:10", "01:10:20", "01:13:40", 
"01:17:00", "01:17:30", "01:19:00", "05:35:30", "05:46:40", "05:22:50", 
"05:20:00", "05:37:40", "05:05:30", "23:18:50", "01:53:20", "23:18:20", 
"21:08:10", "05:48:10", "04:03:10", "05:24:20", "03:21:30", "21:52:10", 
"05:37:30", "05:47:50", "22:36:40", "05:37:20", "05:47:20", "02:50:50", 
"01:43:20", "00:05:00", "06:37:20", "22:25:05", "23:07:39", "21:31:50", 
"05:30:33", "06:29:59", "07:16:03", "22:51:40", "05:52:30", "01:32:10", 
"23:31:31", "05:39:12", "00:04:43", "22:09:20", "22:03:50", "22:29:42", 
"02:54:00", "06:36:26", "00:08:10", "06:52:45", "00:05:03", "23:11:05", 
"04:47:08", "20:01:58", "21:48:20", "03:11:20", "02:03:29", "01:40:49", 
"21:28:40", "06:31:23", "05:54:10", "04:12:12", "03:28:03", "22:43:00", 
"03:32:24", "23:22:40", "00:53:20", "00:20:03", "22:30:46", "21:37:10", 
"22:10:30", "21:58:20", "21:50:50", "21:41:10", "22:14:00", "23:55:00", 
"23:02:30", "00:05:40", "02:25:20", "04:38:10", "05:26:40", "02:54:10", 
"21:53:49", "21:59:33", "21:47:26", "21:48:25", "23:06:47", "23:42:35", 
"03:28:10", "01:43:10", "21:10:16", "02:09:33", "06:19:45", "06:45:01", 
"06:46:55", "07:07:03", "07:03:37", "07:13:02", "07:10:29", "07:17:18", 
"06:53:49", "21:07:24", "21:43:01", "21:43:06", "07:23:13", "07:13:17", 
"21:43:13", "23:01:40", "06:45:39", "22:53:30", "01:26:30", "03:39:20", 
"05:15:53", "05:37:06", "05:15:45", "04:12:17", "22:38:07", "02:27:20", 
"06:02:00", "07:06:58", "21:55:16", "06:41:24", "03:30:50", "20:08:10", 
"06:55:17", "06:02:06", "01:21:00", "21:08:00", "21:55:31", "21:36:30", 
"23:13:47", "23:32:51", "23:27:40", "00:21:40", "22:07:50", "02:46:00", 
"22:34:40", "21:23:20", "22:58:40", "22:59:30", "21:16:20", "03:02:00", 
"23:29:45", "00:32:30", "23:32:53", "23:30:00", "00:17:30", "22:38:10", 
"03:01:50", "22:45:40", "00:52:20", "05:15:31", "20:38:20", "20:51:20", 
"05:52:31", "06:47:31", "07:04:41", "21:59:50", "21:41:30", "22:00:00", 
"22:23:40", "21:38:30", "21:56:30", "22:25:20", "02:08:00", "21:49:20", 
"21:50:40", "03:34:51", "22:50:50", "02:17:40", "21:42:10", "22:16:00", 
"22:28:50", "02:12:00", "02:14:40", "21:57:10", "21:50:10", "21:51:20", 
"21:56:00", "21:56:20", "04:55:31", "21:49:50", "03:33:41", "21:45:10", 
"22:51:00", "03:32:41", "22:28:30", "02:17:00", "21:34:40", "21:39:50", 
"01:46:30", "02:15:10", "20:36:10", "21:22:20", "22:28:00", "22:28:20", 
"22:32:00", "22:43:40", "02:16:40", "21:40:40", "02:09:10", "03:36:01", 
"21:35:10", "21:42:40", "21:51:40", "21:36:40", "02:16:10", "03:37:01", 
"21:19:00", "22:24:00", "03:34:31", "04:55:11", "21:38:50", "01:45:20", 
"21:51:00", "02:12:20", "22:27:20", "01:46:00", "22:27:30", "02:11:00", 
"02:07:10", "21:23:50", "21:46:00", "22:15:40", "22:19:10", "22:24:10", 
"22:48:30", "02:13:00", "21:39:20", "22:15:10", "03:35:41", "21:41:20", 
"21:41:50", "21:44:40", "21:45:00", "02:11:21", "02:13:50", "21:51:50", 
"22:21:00", "22:26:10", "22:47:40", "22:51:30", "03:38:40", "04:55:21", 
"20:39:30", "21:22:50", "02:08:30", "02:13:20", "03:35:11", "03:35:21", 
"03:39:10", "21:31:30", "21:57:30", "21:59:00", "22:49:10", "22:50:10", 
"22:50:20", "02:06:00", "02:12:40", "02:14:10", "03:38:50", "20:36:50", 
"21:40:10", "21:46:20", "22:16:10", "22:27:00", "22:49:20", "01:45:40", 
"03:33:11", "03:36:40", "06:39:11", "03:40:40", "04:20:41", "04:30:41", 
"04:02:01", "20:44:30", "01:38:20", "01:14:40", "07:17:41", "22:42:53", 
"21:40:06", "21:37:31", "23:13:40", "20:36:30", "22:25:34", "23:05:23", 
"21:38:21", "21:39:07", "21:40:47", "21:41:16", "22:15:54", "22:33:26", 
"22:44:52", "23:33:12", "21:29:13", "21:43:48", "20:15:52", "20:18:38", 
"20:26:30", "20:27:56", "20:30:52", "20:34:23", "20:34:48", "22:21:33", 
"22:07:32", "22:24:54", "22:13:35", "22:06:10", "22:06:22", "22:07:01", 
"22:07:39", "22:14:13", "22:06:50", "22:12:21", "22:23:37", "22:26:59", 
"22:27:53", "22:38:34", "22:39:08", "22:28:32", "22:45:08", "22:43:42", 
"22:45:19", "22:40:21", "22:46:36", "22:41:07", "22:48:24", "22:48:57", 
"22:53:03", "22:53:51", "22:52:09", "22:52:35", "23:01:49", "23:01:32", 
"22:54:33", "23:01:01", "23:01:43", "22:54:56", "23:02:02", "23:03:40", 
"23:03:56", "23:10:11", "23:08:43", "23:08:08", "23:10:24", "23:10:17", 
"23:11:56", "23:13:33", "23:13:09", "23:14:44", "23:15:24", "23:15:57", 
"23:16:33", "23:20:15", "21:38:02", "21:38:42", "23:18:56", "21:37:51", 
"21:39:13", "21:39:25", "21:39:38", "21:39:53", "21:42:57", "21:44:30", 
"21:42:08", "21:40:59", "21:47:07", "21:47:12", "21:47:35", "21:51:55", 
"21:47:23", "21:56:55", "21:59:31", "21:57:03", "21:55:56", "21:55:03", 
"22:03:12", "22:03:55", "22:03:36", "22:07:27", "22:15:09", "22:18:07", 
"22:09:08", "22:08:43", "22:11:57", "22:12:35", "22:18:59", "22:19:15", 
"22:22:47", "22:23:34", "22:28:29", "22:28:55", "22:34:52", "22:29:29", 
"22:23:49", "22:33:34", "22:35:21", "22:40:50", "22:41:53", "22:42:09", 
"22:42:01", "22:43:24", "22:43:52", "22:42:17", "22:45:03", "22:45:18", 
"22:46:34", "22:47:08", "22:47:18", "22:47:25", "22:48:00", "22:47:30", 
"22:48:55", "22:49:19", "22:50:23", "22:49:35", "22:48:12", "22:50:13", 
"22:52:00", "22:52:28", "22:56:49", "22:56:01", "22:56:17", "22:57:02", 
"23:06:06", "23:02:34", "23:04:27", "23:08:06", "23:10:47", "23:08:14", 
"23:08:22", "23:13:12", "23:13:18", "23:13:26", "23:18:23", "23:21:05", 
"23:21:21", "23:21:35", "23:22:15", "23:24:24", "23:24:18", "23:24:31", 
"23:26:19", "23:26:01", "23:28:13", "23:31:05", "23:32:21", "23:26:25", 
"23:32:34", "23:33:20", "23:33:48", "23:34:48", "21:29:32", "21:30:11", 
"21:35:21", "21:28:28", "21:40:50", "21:54:05", "21:56:49", "22:12:46", 
"22:11:32", "22:10:42", "21:57:58", "22:12:54", "22:13:05", "22:19:13", 
"22:35:30", "22:43:36", "22:45:41", "22:46:18", "21:19:39", "21:21:41", 
"21:25:48", "22:46:48", "21:31:13", "21:33:37", "21:35:11", "21:35:45", 
"21:55:14", "21:44:27", "21:38:37", "21:36:16", "21:55:50", "21:55:36", 
"21:56:01", "22:05:42", "22:13:34", "22:19:07", "22:19:21", "22:31:32", 
"22:24:08", "22:19:49", "22:28:56", "22:21:56", "22:32:53", "22:34:47", 
"22:34:57", "22:35:35", "22:36:09", "22:37:11", "22:40:40", "22:44:05", 
"20:14:42", "20:14:31", "20:14:51", "22:39:48", "22:42:06", "22:45:50", 
"20:14:58", "20:15:09", "20:15:24", "20:15:31", "20:21:25", "20:16:01", 
"20:16:32", "20:16:25", "20:25:54", "20:22:01", "20:26:48", "20:26:53", 
"20:27:11", "20:28:02", "20:27:39", "20:28:36", "20:29:43", "20:32:06", 
"20:31:25", "20:28:51", "20:31:47", "20:33:09", "20:32:38", "20:34:03", 
"20:33:18", "20:33:32", "20:34:11", "20:34:34", "20:34:57", "20:35:33", 
"20:40:42", "20:40:03", "20:43:41", "20:43:36", "20:42:21", "20:10:31", 
"20:37:12", "21:09:59", "20:41:02", "20:10:01", "21:20:31", "21:20:18", 
"20:32:47", "22:38:02", "22:31:44", "21:54:19", "22:00:33"), class = "factor"), 
    HOUR = c(23L, 2L, 1L, 23L, 1L), DATE.12 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("2024-07-30", "2024-08-05", "2024-09-12", 
    "2024-09-05", "2024-08-02", "2024-08-01", "2024-08-19", "2024-07-20", 
    "2024-07-19", "2024-08-06", "2024-09-15", "2024-07-31", "2024-07-28", 
    "2024-09-06"), class = "factor"), id = c("id_1", "id_1", 
    "id_1", "id_1", "id_1")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")


I have tried this:
result_earliest_adjusted <- id %>% 
  mutate(DATE_TIME = as.POSIXct(paste(DATE, TIME), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) %>% 
  group_by(MANUAL.ID, id, DATE, DATE.12) %>% 
  summarise(Earliest_Time = min(DATE_TIME), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  mutate(Earliest_Time = format(as.POSIXct(Earliest_Time, origin='1970-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

and it kinda works, but the problem is that its based on the column "DATE", which changes day across midnight so i get the earliest value of before and after midnight. I only want the observations for DATE.12, but then I only get the earliest observations after midnight.

I asked about this on staging ground but still don’t understand. When you have DATE in the grouping, the observations before midnight will be in different groups from the observations after midnight, so you’ll get the earliest value from each. If that is not what you want, why not remove DATE from the grouping?

@JonSpring - Your are right, but the code is still not right. it makes mistakes like:
For example when i get result like this:
A tibble: 1 × 7
Groups:   MANUAL.ID, id, DATE.12 [1]
DATE       MANUAL.ID TIME      HOUR DATE.12    id    Earliest_datetime
      
1 2024-08-19 PIPPIP    00:02:35     0 2024-08-19 id_4  2024-08-19 00:02:35
but this result is in the data:

df_4[86:86,]
DATE MANUAL.ID     TIME HOUR    DATE.12   id
86 2024-08-19    PIPPIP 21:56:11   21 2024-08-19 id_4


I think I’ve seen questions with a similar form here. Sometimes people want to define a day as beginning at a different time than midnight. For instance, maybe we want everything after 9 AM to be counted in the day, but everything before 9 AM should be part of the prior day. The typical approach would be to make a variable based on the day -9 hours. Then we group by that and take the minimum.

I assumed that id is the name of the data.frame you provided at the beginning of the question (correct me if otherwise). Could something like this work maybe?
result_earliest_adjusted <- id %>% 
  mutate(DATE_TIME = as.POSIXct(paste(DATE, TIME), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) %>%
  group_by(MANUAL.ID, id, DATE.12) %>%  # group by species, id, and sampling night 
  slice_min(DATE_TIME, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  rename(Earliest_datetime = DATE_TIME)

result_earliest_adjusted

# A tibble: 1 × 7
# Groups:   MANUAL.ID, id, DATE.12 [1]
  DATE       MANUAL.ID TIME      HOUR DATE.12    id    Earliest_datetime  
  <fct>      <fct>     <fct>    <int> <fct>      <chr> <dttm>             
1 2024-08-05 EPTSER    23:55:56    23 2024-08-05 id_1  2024-08-05 23:55:56


It's still not completely bullet-proof. I can still when i look through the data see there is some flaws - for example when i get result like this:
A tibble: 1 × 7
Groups:   MANUAL.ID, id, DATE.12 [1]
DATE       MANUAL.ID TIME      HOUR DATE.12    id    Earliest_datetime
      
1 2024-08-19 PIPPIP    00:02:35     0 2024-08-19 id_4  2024-08-19 00:02:35
but this result is in the data:

df_4[86:86,]
DATE MANUAL.ID     TIME HOUR    DATE.12   id
86 2024-08-19    PIPPIP 21:56:11   21 2024-08-19 id_4


Can you provide more information about these flaws? Or share a new data frame where these flaws are evident?

I would think that it is correct to select 00:02:35 2024/08/19 as the first event in the example you provided, as it is earlier than 21:56:11 2024/08/19,  given that they are both in the same sampling night, no? I would guess that in that case there is an error in the data, as the sampling night for 21:56:11 2024/08/19 should probably be 2024/08/20, while it is still 2024/08/19... Am I missing something?

I have tried to look into it and you might be right. It's completely off for the one dataset (id_4) but it seems to be correct for the other ones. I don't know what im missing either however at first there was some issues with date format , so maybe something happend in the format change.

That makes sense, I hope that the provided code works as intended after fixing the date format!
